# Elements of a TableView Appcelerator Titanium do not respond to click in Android

Tags: android, tableview, titanium, appcelerator

I have a tableView with some rows, after some scrolling up and down the elements of some rows (which exact row changes every time) do not respond anymore to the click event. This happens only on Android devices and only since Titanium SDK 8. Here some sample code:

```
rlvLineTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        backgroundColor: 'white',    
    });

    rlvLineTable.addEventListener('click', testClick);

    img_check[r] = Ti.UI.createImageView({

        name: "img_check"
    });


    var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({  

        index: r,   

    });

row.add(img_check[r]);
var sections = [];
sections.push(row);
rlvLineTable.setData(sections);

...



function testClick(e){


    if (e.source.name != undefined){


        Ti.API.info("cliccato: "+e.index+ "  "+e.source.name);


        switch(e.source.name){

            case "img_check":
                enableRowRiv(e);
                break;


            default:

                Ti.API.info("name: "+e.source.name);
                break;
        }
    }else

        Ti.API.info("undefined");

}
```

After some scrolling, some of the rows, when clicked on the imageView (or any other element), do not fire the click event. But if I click on the empty space of the row, the click fires.

I'm really getting crazy with this, do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug and was fixed in 9.0.2.GA (9.0.3.GA is already available): 
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-27499

That said: there is currently some testing going on if the bug still appears in some setups! So it might be fixed for you if you update to 9.0.3.GA. Otherwise you'll need to wait for a fix (and keep an eye on this ticket or attached tickets if a new one is created)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am already using the 9.0.3.GA and I still got the problem. Then the only thing I can do it's to wait and hope :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to fix this. You have to add the listener to "singletap" instead of "click".